# How to throw an exception in ZSH

Tags: zsh

I am writing a function and I want to throw an exception when the input is invalid. When I googled I found that there is a `throw MyException` command but when I try to use it like this:

```
#!  /usr/bin/zsh
throw Exception
```

The script throws the following error:

```
$ ./test.sh                         
./test.sh:2: command not found: throw
```

Is there an mechanism to throw error in ZSH? If so are there any resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`throw` and `catch` must be loaded first; they aren't built directly into the shell.

```
autoload throw catch
```

They are documented in `zshcontrib(1)`, under [`EXCEPTION HANDLING`](http://info2html.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/info2html-demo/info2html?(zsh)Exception%2520Handling), although it isn't immediately obvious that they need to be loaded.